# Multiple filter conditions Azure table storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

How can I set multiple filters on a Azure Table Storage?

This is what I've tried:

```
string partitionFilter = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "partition1");
string date1 = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("Date", QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual, "31-8-2013T14:15:14Z");
string date2 = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("Date", QueryComparisons.LessThanOrEqual, "31-8-2013T14:15:14Z");
string finalFilter = TableQuery.CombineFilters(partitionFilter, TableOperators.And, date1);
```

This doesn't work because `TableQuery.CombineFilters()` only takes 3 parameters. And I need an extra parameter for the 2nd date.

My second try:

```
string filter = "PartitionKey eq 'partition1' and Date ge datetime'31-8-2013T14:15:14Z' and Date lt datetime'31-8-2013T14:19:10Z'";
TableQuery<CustomEntity> query = new TableQuery<CustomEntity>().Where(filter).Take(5);
```

This returns `400 bad request`. But if I remove the 'datetime' it runs but returns no results while it should return a few 100 records.

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd894031) doc from msdn, that is how datetimes should be formatted.

My result should be all records that are between two dates.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

First "and" your partition filter with one of the date filters, then "and" the intermediate result with the other date filter.

```
string date1 = TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate(
                   "Date", QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual,
                   DateTimeOffsetVal);
string date2 = TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate(
                   "Date", QueryComparisons.LessThanOrEqual,
                   DateTimeOffsetVal);
string finalFilter = TableQuery.CombineFilters(
                        TableQuery.CombineFilters(
                            partitionFilter,
                            TableOperators.And,
                            date1),
                        TableOperators.And, date2);
```

Comment: I tried your solution, it compiles and runs, but no records are returned. Are there any special 'things' i have to do for `DateTime` comparisions that you are aware of?

Comment: It seems that there are different enums for every datatype of filter you do. And for date it's `TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate`. And this did the trick. Damith, can you set this too in your answer?

Answer (score 17):

I am using [Windows Azure Storage 7.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/) and you can use Linq query so that you don't need to combine filters anymore:

```
// filter dates for test
var startDate = DateTime.Parse("01/02/2016 12:00:00 AM"); 
var endDate = DateTime.Parse("02/02/2016 12:00:00 AM");

// Get the cloud table
var cloudTable = GetCloudTable();

// Create a query: in this example I use the DynamicTableEntity class
var query = cloudTable.CreateQuery<DynamicTableEntity>()
        .Where(d => d.PartitionKey == "partition1"
               && d.Timestamp >= startDate && d.Timestamp <= endDate);

// Execute the query
var result = query.ToList();
```

Here is the generated query :

> ((PartitionKey eq 'partition1') and (Timestamp ge datetime'2016-01-31T11:00:00Z')) and (Timestamp le datetime'2016-02-01T11:00:00Z')

You can notice that:

- The filters have been combined.
- The dates have been converted to UTC.

Comment: Does it a hard requirement for the partition and row keys (if used) are provided in the query?  Otherwise, how do I ensure I'm not scanning the entire table?

Comment: @CamHart If you don't specify PartitionKey and RowKey, you are going to perform a table scan

Answer (score 15):

> How can I set multiple filters on a Azure Table Storage?

I was wondering the same thing. I wrote an extension to the TableQuery class which works fine.

It's an easy change which makes me wonder if we are going about querying with multiple filters incorrectly.

```
public static class TableQueryExtensions 
{
    public static TableQuery<TElement> AndWhere<TElement>(this TableQuery<TElement> @this, string filter)
    {
        @this.FilterString = TableQuery.CombineFilters(@this.FilterString, TableOperators.And, filter);
        return @this;
    }

    public static TableQuery<TElement> OrWhere<TElement>(this TableQuery<TElement> @this, string filter)
    {
        @this.FilterString = TableQuery.CombineFilters(@this.FilterString, TableOperators.Or, filter);
        return @this;
    }

    public static TableQuery<TElement> NotWhere<TElement>(this TableQuery<TElement> @this, string filter)
    {
        @this.FilterString = TableQuery.CombineFilters(@this.FilterString, TableOperators.Not, filter);
        return @this;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are adding multiple `Or` filters, then `FilterString` will look like `((() or (Foo eq '1')) or (Foo eq '2')) or (Foo eq '3')`. If `FilterString` is empty, add just the filter itself: `@this.FilterString = @this.FilterString == null ? filter : TableQuery.CombineFilters(@this.FilterString, TableOperators.Or, filter);`.

Answer (score 10):

Just wanted to add one more answer.

```
string filter = "PartitionKey eq 'partition1' and Date ge datetime'31-8-2013T14:15:14Z' and Date lt datetime'31-8-2013T14:19:10Z'";
TableQuery<TablePost> query = new TableQuery<TablePost>().Where(filter).Take(5);
```

The reason code above is failing is because the date/time value must be entered in `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ` format. So your query should be:

```
string filter = "(PartitionKey eq 'partition1') and (Date ge datetime'2013-08-31T14:15:14Z' and Date lt datetime'2013-08-31T14:19:10Z')";
TableQuery<TablePost> query = new TableQuery<TablePost>().Where(filter).Take(5);
```

Comment: what is Take(5) here?

Comment: Fetch 5 entities.

Comment: ok got it  5 entities.

Answer (score 3):

Just handling the case of a new query that does not have a filter already and based on @LivingOnACloud, I would rather write it this way:

```
 public static TableQuery<TElement> AndWhere<TElement>(this TableQuery<TElement> query, string filter)
            where TElement : ITableEntity,new ()
        {
            if (query.FilterString.IsNullOrEmpty())
            {
                query.FilterString =  filter;
            }
            else
            {
                query.FilterString = TableQuery.CombineFilters(query.FilterString, TableOperators.And, filter);
            }
            return query;
        }
```

And the rest follow the same check, things can go nicer.