# Multiple query parameter in azure table storage with function

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

Can not pass two parameter on azure table storage within azure function.

**What I have tried:**

*My parameter on function:*

```
        // convert all request perameter into Json object
```

```cs
        var content = req.Content;
        string jsonContent = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        dynamic requestPram = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product(jsonContent);


        // extract each param
        string product = requestPram.product;

        string version = requestPram.version;
```

*My storage query*

```cs
 var query = new TableQuery()
                {
                    FilterString = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("ProductName", QueryComparisons.Equal, product),
                    SelectColumns = new string[] {
                    "ProductName","EntitledProductsCurrentPrevious","MainstreamSupportEndDate"
                },
                    TakeCount = 200
                };
```

Here I have passed on param "product" Its work fine and return expected data. but I want to  pass also version . **Similar like sql WHERE product = 'proudctname' and version = 'versionName'**

**Just Like following TSQL**

```
SELECT Product,EntitledProductsCurrentPrevious,MainstreamSupportEndDate 
FROM BotProductList 
WHERE Product = 'Microsoft Dynamics CRM' AND 
EntitledProductsCurrentPrevious = '2016'
```

***I have followed below reference:***

[reference_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18549555/multiple-filter-conditions-azure-table-storage)

[reference_2](https://vkinfotek.com/azureqa/how-do-i-query-azure-table-storage-using-tablequery-class.html)

[reference_3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21167680/querying-windows-azure-table-storage-with-multiple-query-criteria/21173271)

But Still cannot solve it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `string finalFilter = TableQuery.CombineFilters(productQuery, TableOperators.And, versionQuery);` instead.

Comment: You're welcome. Your code below also works since it directly constructs the query string.

Comment: Yeah, Also query string need not to convert on storage environment as it can directly be run there on the other hand linq needed to be convert each time which sometimes a little costly.

Answer (score 2):

***After many struggling I have solved this problem in below format:***

```cs
var query = new TableQuery()
                {
                    FilterString = string.Format("PartitionKey eq '{0}' and RowKey eq '{1}'", product, version),
                    SelectColumns = new string[] {
                    "ProductName","EntitledProductsCurrentPrevious","MainstreamSupportEndDate"
                },
                    TakeCount = 200
                };
```

***It also reduced some line of code.***